# Does there exist a function whose range is the complement of the range of this function?

Tags: calculus, inverse

Does this function have a **complement** on the positive integers in the sense that the range of the complement should be the complement of the range of the function?

$$\frac{1}{8} \left(1-(-1)^n+2 n (2+n)\right)$$

Here is the inverse/complement which I got from Generic Human:

$$\left\lfloor \sqrt{4 n-1}\right\rfloor +n+1$$

Edit per @robjohn:

Domain is $\mathbb{N}$. I'm trying to use the [Lambek-Moser theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambek%E2%80%93Moser_theorem) to generate complimentary sets.

The formula generates the pronic numbers interleaved with the squares.
$\{1,2,4,6,9,12,16,20,25,30\}$

I want to generate the complementary set of everything else.
$\{3,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,15,17\}$

**The Lambek-Moser theorem uses the inverse to generate the complement.**

My question is: am I interpreting this scenario properly?

Comment: What is its domain? Its range?

Comment: If the domain is $\mathbb{N}$ and you are asking whether the "map" is injective, the answer is yes. The quadratic part is injective, and the term $(-1)^n$ is irrelevant for $n$ sufficiently large. You need to check the the "first" terms are distinct. http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5B1-%28-1%29%5En%2B2+n+%282%2Bn%29%2C%7Bn%2C20%7D%5D

Comment: would you add that to the question, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Note: If all you care about is existence of such a function, then the Lambek-Moser theorem guarantees the existence of such a function simply because $F$ is increasing. But if you want a nice closed-form expression, then Lambek-Moser doesn't tell you that it exists, it can just help you find it.*

In the context of the Lambek-Moser theorem, you have the increasing function from $\mathbb N^*\to\mathbb N^*$:
$$F(2k)=k(k+1)\\
F(2k+1)=(k+1)^2$$
Define $f(n)=F(n)-n$, which happens to coincide with $F(n-2)$:
$$f(2k)=k(k-1)\\
f(2k+1)=(k-1)^2$$
Since $f(2k)=(k-1/2)^2-1/4$, we can write $$f(n)=\left\lfloor \frac{(n-1)^2}{4} \right\rfloor$$
Given $n\ge 1$, we're looking for $p\ge 0$ such that
$$f(p)<n\le f(p+1)$$
$$\frac{(p-1)^2}{4}<n\le \frac{p^2}{4}$$
$$(p-1)^2<4n\le p^2$$
$$(p-1)^2\le 4n-1<p^2$$
$$p-1=\lfloor \sqrt{4n-1} \rfloor$$
giving us finally:
$$f^*(n)=1+\lfloor \sqrt{4n-1} \rfloor$$
$$\boxed{G(n)=1+n+\left\lfloor \sqrt{4n-1} \right\rfloor}$$
so that $\{F(n):n\ge 1\}$ and $\{G(n):n\ge 1\}$ form a partition of $\mathbb N^*$.

Comment: In fact, because a square is always congruent to 0 or 1 mod 4, $$\lfloor\sqrt{4n-1}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{4n-2}\rfloor = \lfloor\sqrt{4n-3}\rfloor$$ so the expressions are equivalent.

Comment: It is not entirely correct that Lambek-Moser theorem doesn't tell how to construct the enumeration of the complement. The functions in Lambek-Moser are related by the condition $f(n)\leq m\iff n\leq g(m)$ (which some call $f,g$ being a Galois connection). This allows writing $f(n)=\min\{m:\ m\leq g(n)\}$ and $g(n)=\max\{m:\ f(m)\leq n\}$. This is  an explicit formula for $g$ in terms of $f$ and it can be made even more explicit when you note that the right side can be written in terms of the floor function. This is why the floor function appears in most problems of this type.

Answer (score 5):

$f(-2)=f(-1)=f(0)=0$ so if the domain is the integers it does not have an inverse. In fact, $f(n)=f(-2-n)$

However, this function is monotonic increasing on the non-negative integers, so it does have an inverse if the domain is the non-negative integers.

---

Suppose
$$
m=\frac18\left(1-(-1)^n+2n(2+n)\right)
$$
If $n$ is even, then $(n+1)^2=4m+1$

If $n$ is odd, then $(n+1)^2=4m$

Therefore, here is the inverse:

If $4m$ is a perfect square, then $n=\sqrt{4m}-1$

If $4m+1$ is a perfect square, then $n=\sqrt{4m+1}-1$

If neither $4m$ nor $4m+1$ is a perfect square, then $m$ is not in the range of the function.

Comment: The OP wrote that the domain is $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: @Siminore: Thanks. That was added after I started writing my answer, so I didn't see it. However, that part should actually be in the question, not the comments.

Comment: @FredDanielKline: what kind of inverse do you need? Why does the inverse I give explicitly above not work?

Comment: @robjohn, I added two examples to the OP.

Comment: @FredDanielKline: So you don't really want an [inverse](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_function) to your function. From your example it looks as if you want a function that generates the complement of the range of the given function. This is a different question altogether. Not only was the question confusing, but also that you accepted [clark's answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/165287), since it answers the same question that my answer does.

Answer (score 4):

write $a_n = \frac{1}{8} \left(1-(-1)^n+2 n (2+n)\right)$ then 
$a_{n+1}-a_n=\frac{1}{8} \left(1-(-1)^n+2(n+1)(3+n)-(1-(-1)^n+2 n (2+n)\right)
=$ $\frac{1}{8} ( (-1)^{n+2}+{-1}^n+10n+6)) \geq \frac{1}{8} (-2+6+10n) >0$ since $a_n$ is increasing it is $1-1$ and it can be inverted using as domain its range.